# VSCODE 2017 Literal templating not detected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I'm using `VSCODE` 2017 and I'm having trouble with `ES6` syntax.

I have a `const` called port declared, and I'm trying to use `es6` literal templating to inject it in a string in the image below.

When the code is executed, the port variable is not being injected, nor has my IDE changed the colour of the `${port}` syntax to blue, so it makes me believe it's not recognising the `es6` syntax.

[image: String Literal Not Detected]

Comment: It's not recognised as ES6 interpolation syntax because it is not ES6 template literal syntax :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backticks (`) not double quotes ("). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals